# How to check if two lists have the same value and remove the value from one of them

Tags: c#, .net

I have two lists, one comes from user input and the other from a database. I want to check if the user enters a string already in the database list, and hence remove that string from the list the user enters. I have tried the code below

```
foreach (string name in listOfStudentName) 
{
  if(_studentsInDatabase.Count > 0)
  {
        foreach (string nameFromDatabase in _studentsInDatabase)
        {
             If (name == nameFromDatabase)
              {
                   listOfStudentName.RemoveAll(item => item == name); 
                   break;

              }
         }
   }
}
```

This code removes only the first element that is in both lists then throws an exception `System.InvalidOperationExceptiom: 'Collection was modified; enumeration may not execute.`

I should add that I need to be able to notify the user as each duplicate is removed, for example a message box saying "name1 was removed" displayed after each repetition is removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot remove items from a collection while you enumerate them in a `foreach`.

Why not simply(this one liner replaces your whole code):

```
listOfStudentName.RemoveAll(_studentsInDatabase.Contains);
```

If you need to do something for every user-name that was already in the database:

```
var alreadyInDatabase = listOfStudentName.Intersect(_studentsInDatabase);
foreach (string username in alreadyInDatabase)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{username} was removed, it is already in the database");
}

var notInDatabase = listOfStudentName.Except(_studentsInDatabase);
listOfStudentName = notInDatabase.ToList();
```

Comment: This works, thanks. However I need to notify the user each time a duplicate value is removed. For example showing a message box saying "Name1 was removed, it is already in the database". How would I work that into your solution?

Comment: @VincentN.: is `_studentsInDatabase` a `List<string>` or a database query?

Comment: It is a string.

Comment: @VincentN.: look at my second approach

Comment: This works, thanks. I'm not exactly sure how. I'm just learning programming. I'll look up the methods and see how it works. Could you suggest why I was downvoted please? It would help me ask better questions.

Comment: @VincentN.probably duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using foreach loop, There is no need to use it. Simply get the entered string and match with that string with _studentsInDatabase list. If you match entered string than remove last added item from listOfStudentName list

```
        List<string> listOfStudentName = new List<string>();
        List<string> _studentsInDatabase = new List<string>();

        listOfStudentName .Add("User 1");
        listOfStudentName .Add("User 2");
        listOfStudentName .Add("User 3");
        listOfStudentName .Add("User 4");
        listOfStudentName .Add("User 5");



        _studentsInDatabase .Add("User 11");
        _studentsInDatabase .Add("User 22");
        _studentsInDatabase .Add("User 23");
        _studentsInDatabase .Add("User 24");
        _studentsInDatabase .Add("User 5");



        var index = _studentsInDatabase .FindIndex(x => x == "User 5");
        if(index!=-1)
            listOfStudentName .RemoveAt(listOfStudentName .Count-1);
```

Or you can do one thing that First match entered string and if you find that string into database list than no need to be add it into userList that would also work